# how to get ordinal position of element in a large json data with php

Tags: php, json

I have large json data which is contains hundreds thousands elements, now i need to get the ordinal position of an item inside the data with php. what is the best approach to do this rather than having loop because performance is important in this case.

Seems PHPLINQ looks promising but performance not so good.

Comment: Do you have control of the data?

Comment: Yes i do, but changing the structure could be a lot of workaround since the source is not from structurized database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am stick with [PHPLINQ](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/) instead which mimic C# LINQ works ok

Answer (score 0):

I would use json_decode(), array_keys() or array_values() depending on whether you are searching for a key or a value, and array_search().
I assumed the depth of your array is 1, am I right?

Comment: its large data with multi level array 4-5 level depth, thats why i am considering to have something like LINQ search method or XPATH